# Retrieving image from a server in a Fragment

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to update a ImageView with a image on a server. I'm using Prime library (https://github.com/DHuckaby/Prime). But for some reason, it crashes.

The img link is:

```
http://192.168.1.36/testing/fotos/foto1.jpg
```

The code is like this (note that it's a fragment, maybe this is the key...):

```
public class MyFragmentA extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    try {
        String imageURL = "http://192.168.1.36/mimicit/fotos/foto1.jpg";
        Log.d("errors", "Got the link");
        RemoteImageView remoteImageView = (RemoteImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Log.d("errors", "Done this part");
        remoteImageView.setImageURL(imageURL);
        Log.d("errors", "Done this other part");
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("errors", "Wohoops. Crashed");
    }

    return myFragmentView;
}
```

As you can see, there are some logs in the middle, so I can know exactly where it crashed.

This is the log result:

```
01-04 14:15:46.363: D/errors(1030): Got the link
01-04 14:15:46.363: D/errors(1030): Wohoops. Crashed
```

I though that maybe the problem was that the URL wasn't working on the emulator, but browsered it and its displaying normally:

[image]

Where do you think the problem is?

Maybe I should download the img async? Is that a big deal? I mean, would it crash if not? Would try, but I'm not sure about how to doing it async mode...

Thank you.

Sergi

Comment: You're catching every possible exception.  It would help greatly if you caught specific exceptions or let the program crash out so you can tell exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Also, getView() returns null in `onCreateView()` because you haven't created the view yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line of code :

```
RemoteImageView remoteImageView = (RemoteImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

with:

```
RemoteImageView remoteImageView = (RemoteImageView) myFragmentView .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

The Reason its is throwing Error is you haven't returned View from onCreateView() and calling getView() which you will get as Null. So you just findViewById with respective to your myFragmentView.

Comment: This is crashing the whole app, it doesn't even get into the exception. But with this, the log is displaying this: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.handlerexploit.prime.widgets.RemoteImageView. Trying to figure out what's wrong. Will update you soon

Comment: This is now the issue: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.handlerexploit.prime.widgets.RemoteImageView`

Comment: have you added that RemoteImageView library project to your project.

Comment: Yep. That was it. Finally i stoped using that library, coz it gave me some troubles I couldn't fix. Decided to use a simple one. Gave internet permissions and its working. So you got the answer on those crashing problems.